# Unitled section in Lyx

Tags: sectioning, lyx

I am writing a Lyx document with untitled sections. As Lyx does not permit to create untitled sections, I use to insert the latex code `\section`, but it would be very much convenient to have "Lyx sections", in order to have it in the plan of the document and to see the numbers. I could name the section with a blank, but it would be weird. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want only the section numbers? What is the problem using `\section{}` with empty argument?

Comment: With a the latex input \section{}, I can't see the numeros of the sections in the lyx document, even if it eventually appears in the pdf, in my document these numeros are important and there are many sections. What's more, it's not taken into account by Lyx for the plan of the document, and I would like to be able to jump quickly to, say, section 57.

Comment: Did you consider to use another editor? Nowadays they are very powerful to navigate between the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Insert your numbered sections and then, right after the number, right click and select `Insert Short Title`. Leave that title blank, click behind the small red frame and Press `<Enter>`. You will be on a new line where you can enter text, with the numbered section intact and the short title not printing.

Does that give you what you need?

Comment: Well it works but there is a new problem: I need the untitled sections in the part II and the numerotation resumes from part I, so my first untitled section is numbered 74. In fact, the untitled sections of the part II are the solutions of the sections of the part I, so I need it to be numbered properly in order to navigate the document.